# ByteArray OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, arrays, filestream

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
   var data = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

I have an OutOfMemoryException thrown at that line (not during the stream reading, but during the byte initialization:

```
data = new byte[stream.Length];
```

**[EDIT 15-12-2015]**

The filesize is about 600MB, but it may go up to 2GB.

The shorter version of the code also fails:

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

Comment: How big is the file you are attempting to read?

Comment: What size is `stream.Length`?

Comment: What's the value of `stream.Length`?

Comment: Side note: `var data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` is a shorter version of the code.

Comment: It is most likely the file you are trying to read is too large. What are you planning to do with `data`. May be you  may not need to load all file in to memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your file size is over **2 GB** and you're using **32-bit system**? It looks like you're exceeding the limits, No single object can be larger than 2 GB(in case of 32-bit systems at least). Consider streaming the data instead.
But with .NET Framework 4.5, you can use `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` Element which supports you use objects that are greater than 2 GB in total size.

Here is the configuration you'll have to use;

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Updated the answer!

Comment: I'm limited to .Net 4.0 :(

Comment: @user2567674 What do you plan to do with the data? Maybe you can do it in chunks.

Comment: I plan on sending it through webservices to server, and write it a DB.

Comment: @user2567674 I don't think storing a file bigger than 2 GB to a DB is a good idea. I'm not even sure which of the databases allow you to do that.

Comment: I can't argue it would be a good idea, that's for sure! I just can't really tell why, from a pure technical point. What do you think should the threshold be? (average size of the DB is 20G by default).